# conditional equation in latex

Tags: equations

how can I write this formula by latex
[image]

Comment: Use the `cases` environment from `amsmath`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Please avoid "do this for me" questions, you should at least post a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) to show your efforts. Also, please mark and upvote the correct answer. Enjoy this community!

Answer (score 5):

One way is to use:

```
\begin{align}
p_{i \, j} = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{|p_{i}|} & \text{if $P_{i}$ links to $P_{j}$} \\
0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}
\end{align}
```

where `align` is used for spacing around the equation(s) or an inline version is:

```
 $$ p_{i \, j} = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{|p_{i}|} & \text{if $P_{i}$ links to $P_{j}$} \\
 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$
```

The results can be viewed as (in their respective order):
[image]

Comment: Nice answer. An image of the output would be handy!

Comment: One minor tweak: you might want `\lvert p_{i} \rvert`, so as to space the absolute-value bars as left and right delimiters.

Comment: `align` is not intended for single equation.

Comment: Usage of `$$` is deprecated in LaTeX. Instead it you should use `\[` and `\]` or `\begin{equation}` and `\end{equation}` (see my answer).  You should provide an MWE, which reproduce showed image. And let me repeat, your use of `align` in the first example is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

With use of `cases*` and/or `dcases?`defined in the `mathtools` package and defining `\abs{...}` as pair of delimiters for absolute value:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
p_{ij} = \begin{cases*} 
    \dfrac{1}{\abs{p_{i}}}   & if $P_{i}$ links to $P_{j}$ \\
                    0       & otherwise 
             \end{cases*}
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
p_{ij} = \begin{dcases*} 
    \frac{1}{\abs{p_{i}}}   & if $P_{i}$ links to $P_{j}$ \\
                    0       & otherwise 
             \end{dcases*}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Neat! Curious to the thought behind the `\,` extra space between the indices?

Comment: @Holene, oh, they are superfluous ... deleted now. Thank you very much to point me on this.